# A problem about friends

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> If $n>2$, prove that you can put $n$ people into $2$ groups so that the number of acquaintances of each person in the same group is no more than the number of acquaintances in the other group.

If we give each person a score which equals to the number of acquaintances in his own group minus the acquaintances in the other group, I suppose that the method for which the sum of scores of each person reaches its minimum value satisfy the requirements.

To prove this, we need reductio ad absurdum. Suppose that this is not true, then there can be a way to adjust how the people are grouped so that the sum of scores gets even smaller, but is there such a way to adjust? In addition, I thought about changing the person who has more acquaintances in his own group than in the other group (that is to say the person who does not meet the requirements) into the other group. This makes sure that this person gets less points but other people may get points as a result of this change.

Are there any ways to improve this into a correct proof?

PS if the tag isn’t correct change it for me.

Comment: The negation of "there is a way (statement is true)" is "for EVERY way (statement is false)". But you are treating the negation as "there is a way (statement is false)", which is not correct.

Comment: That’s not what I mean. I just want to prove that the way for which the sum of scores of each person reaches its maximum value satisfy the requirements. And using the  reductio ad absurdum, we need to show that when there is a way to adjust the grouping and make the sum of scores larger if there is a person who doesn’t meet the requirement. This contradicts with the scores sum up to its maximum value. @PaulSinclair

Comment: if you saw it, my induction idea had a flaw, so I deleted it. But if you are trying to maximize scores to find the solution, then you need to reverse your score definition. Aquaintances in the other group need to exceed aquaintances in the same group, not the other way around.

Comment: Oh that’s right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the split in two groups which maximizes the number of edges with ends in different groups. Then assume that there is one person who has more friends in the group then outside, and see what happens when they are moved to the other group.

Comment: Can you tell the main difference between your solution and my scoring method?

Comment: I think your method just looks more complicated because you assign scores to every person and then add them up. But in practice they are almost the same. Consider an edge between people of different groups. Your method will count this as $-1$ twice (once for each person). Similarly for edge between persons in the same group, it will count as $+1$ twice. So your total sum of scores is really $2 \times$ total number of edges - $4 \times$ the number of edges between people in different groups.